# Angular Template Interpolation Slow to Respond

Tags: javascript, angular

My Angular template needs to display a rapidly changing value, driven by mousemove events, which I am retrieving from my NgRx Store. The Store appears to be keeping up with the data changes but the resulting value displayed in the template lags behind and appears to only refresh when the mouse stops moving.

A component with approximately 300 DOM elements detects mousemove events and handles them outside of ngZone as follows:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {

    const eventElement = this.eventDiv.nativeElement;

    this.move$ = fromEvent(eventElement, 'mousemove');
    this.leave$ = fromEvent(eventElement, 'mouseleave');

    /*
     * We are going to detect mouse move events outside of
     * Angular's Zone to prevent Change Detection every time
     * a mouse move event is fired.
     */
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

      // Check we have a move$ and leave$ objects.
      if (this.move$ && this.leave$) {

        // Configure moveSubscription.
        this.moveSubscription = this.move$.pipe(
          takeUntil(this.leave$),
          repeat()).subscribe((e: MouseEvent) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.mouseMove.emit(e);

          });
      };

    });
```

A parent component handles the resulting mouseMove event and still outside ngZone performs some Calculations to ascertain which element the mouse is over. Once the result has been calculated a function is called, passing in the calculated result, and within this function I dispatch an NgRx Action within ngZone using `this.ngZone.run(() => { dispatch Action here }`.

I can see that the Store reacts quickly to the changing data. I then have a separate component responsible for displaying the result. An Observable listens to the Selector's changing values and displays the result using interpolation.

Curiously I added an RxJs `tap` into the Observable declaration as follows:

```
  public mouseoverLocationName$: Observable<string | null>;

  constructor(
    public store: Store<fromPilecapReducers.PilecapState>
  ) {

    this.mouseoverLocationName$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(fromPilecapSelectors.PilecapMapSelectors.selectMouseoverLocationName),
      tap(locationName => {
        console.log(`mouseoverLocation$: ${locationName}`);
      })
    );

  }
```

The console logs out the `locationName` value nice and quickly. However the html element displaying the string is very slow and, as I said earlier, only appears to update when the mouse stops moving. The template code is as follows:

```
<h2>{{mouseoverLocationName$ | async}}</h2>
```

I've got to the point now where I can't see the wood for the trees! any suggestions or guidance very welcome.

Comment: I think the problem is async pipe only marks your component as diry and lets angular decide when to update the view. I'm not sure but can u try to use detectChanges() or ngrxPush pipe?

Comment: Without having a look at your component tree, it is very hard to understand what is going on. The async pipe triggers change detection with the method `markForCheck` and if the component that renders the events have a lot of child components, those need to be "rechecked". If you just want to update the view when an event occurs, you are better off accessing the DOM directly and perform that change yourself. Even though it is discouraged to access the DOM directly using Angular, sometimes it is necessary, so it really depends on the use case.

Comment: Also, you can try to use the profiler in the Angular DevTools to inspect how long each change detection cycle is taking and which component is responsible for that, it could help you to identify the issue.

Comment: These are all helpful thanks. Let me look into each suggestion and get back.

Comment: I refactored my code to simplify it. Ultimately my NgRx Store is updating a property and this is being passed to a display component using a Selector. In my display component I added a `console.log()` to the setter of the `@Input()` and the value is changing rapidly. The object being passed is immutable (`strictStateImmutability: true`) and I also tried including `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` but even though I can see in the console the value changing the Template is not updating. Only when my mouse stops moving does the template update.